# How to make wxpython PropertyGrid DirProperty offer new folder on osx

Tags: wxpython

Using wxpython, I am instantiating a wxpg.PropertyGrid with a wxpg.DirPropery element:

```
#http://wxpropgrid.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index
import wx.propgrid as wxpg

#...

    this_backup = wxpg.PropertyGrid(self._mainDisplay, wx.NewId(), 
                                    style = wxpg.PG_SPLITTER_AUTO_CENTER) 
    this_backup.Bind( wxpg.EVT_PG_CHANGED, self.OnBackupGridChange )

    this_backup.Append( wxpg.DirProperty("Backup Root",value=backup['Backup Root']))
```

Under Windows, when this code runs and I press on the "browse" elipsis for the dir property entry, I get a dialog that allows me to create a new directory as the selection.

However, under osx 10.8.2, there appears to be no way to create a new directory in the same dialog.

How can I persude osx to use the dialog for a directory selection that offers "new folder" as one of the options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does it work in the wxPython demo? Looking at the demo code, it looks like it overrides the OnEvent method to display a wx.DirDialog. If that doesn't work, then perhaps Mac's native dialog doesn't allow that capability.

Of course, since you're overriding the event, you can use any dialog of your choosing, so you could switch to using the MultiDirDialog (wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog) instead. It's a pure Python widget, so it should work.

EDIT (10/15/12):

In my wxPython 2.9 Demo, I have the following event handler:

```
def OnEvent(self, propgrid, primaryEditor, event):
    if event.GetEventType() == wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED:
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(propgrid,
                           _("Select a directory to be added to "
                             "the list:"))

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            new_path = dlg.GetPath()
            old_value = self.m_value
            if old_value:
                new_value = list(old_value)
                new_value.append(new_path)
            else:
                new_value = [new_path]
            self.SetValueInEvent(new_value)
            retval = True
        else:
            retval = False

        dlg.Destroy()
        return retval

    return False
```

To me, that looks like the demo creator over rid the OnEvent method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your questions and hints.

I went to the wxPython demo and opened the PropertyGrid, then browsed for a new directory in it's  DirProperty row    It opens the same directory select dialog that my app does: the "basic" version that does not offer "create a new folder" option.

However, it is surely not the case that osx doesn't have this capabilty, because most of the day to day apps that I use open a different dialog - one that has a "new folder" button in the bottom right.   This dialog looks the same for Chrome, Office For Mac etc

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't yet understand the second part of your answer.   I am using the wxpg.DirProperty behaviour when the browse button that it creates is pressed, not overriding it.   So I appear to be saddled with whatever dialog it brings up - that's why I'm thinking I somehow need to tell it (or osx) that I want the advanced version of the dialog...